# Android sqlite - change default db rights by Java code

Tags: android, database, sqlite, chmod, access-rights

Each time my app updates the data of my DB, default rights are **RW-RW----**!

So each time I want to export my DB from Eclipse-DDMS to my PC, to check, I first have to make a chmod 777 on the .db file (adb shell), to restore the **RWXRWXRWX** rights.

That's not really fun!

So my question is: how could I do, in my Java code, to make a kind of "chmod 777", after all DB updates?

I already checked-out the SQLiteOpenHelper & Database classes, but found no functions dealing with the right...

Comment: what is the relation between your code and the eclipse export of your db?

Comment: also, what is the point of `+x`ing a db file?

Comment: +x is just an example! But I finally found out: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R 777" + dbfile);

Comment: also, if that's a .db *file*, `-R` is not very useful

Comment: plus you missed a space in your command

Comment: please do post it as an answer (and accept it) just in case someone else has this rather unusual need